# Running jobs through ssh (linux/osx)

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, executable

I was wondering if it was possible to execute jobs via ssh.  In particular I have a different list of input files on a number of machines that all have the same executable in the same place.  Is there some command which means I dont have to move from machine to machine using ssh and set them running individually.  The sort of thing I had in mind would be something like:

ssh RemoteMachine1:./Executable ~/Inputfile_1
ssh RemoteMachine2:./Executable ~/Inputfile_2

which could be run from my host machine?
Thanks in advance
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/).

"Fabric is a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks."

Answer (score 1):

If you can write Perl, try [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aParallel).

For instance:

```
my %file = (host1 => file1,
             host2 => file2,
             ...);

my $pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new();

for my $host (keys %files) {
    $pssh->add_host($host);
    $pssh->push($host, 'cmd',
                {stdout_file => "$host.out"},
                './Executable', $file{$host});

}

$pssh->run
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually can run the `batch` command thru `ssh` ; read more about [batch](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/batch.htm) command and [batch processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing).

You might also be interested by [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) or [DSH](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en) or [SQS](http://sqs.sourceforge.net/)